# Ubuntu 14.04 sudden freezes and 100% disk usage

Tags: 14.04, flash, freeze, disk-usage

Sometimes I just casually browse web and out of nowhere my disk is usage is 100% and everything freezes. I have 64 bits ubuntu 14.04 with all updates. My pc spec is i5 4670k, integrated GPU and 4gb of ram. My hdd is seagate 1TB (I don't recall its full name). Freezes happen a few times a day. Only running apps are: Chrome, Banshee and thunderbird. It might have something to do with flash, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Is this a recent installation of Ubuntu?

Comment: Yup, I installed it like 2 weeks ago.

Comment: I would say you need to download a new Ubuntu image, make a USB out of it and reinstall. It sounds like a problem that I had a while ago and in the end the only thing that fixed it was a clean re-install.

Comment: Get more RAM...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your physical RAM is getting full and the system starts to use the Swap. Programmes like Chromium can easily take up several Gb of RAM. On 12.04, with about 20 tabs open [Chromium would get up to 2 Gb of RAM in less than a day](http://attheedgeoftime.blogspot.com/2013/08/why-i-had-to-quit-using-chromium.html).

You can start by monitoring closely your free RAM with the **System Monitor**. See if these episodes of high disk usage coincide with a full (or near full) RAM. If that is the case then try to understand if any programme stands out; both Chromium and Thunderbird could be the culprits.

In any case, if you are used to have multiple tabs open in your web browser, I would definitely advise you to use Firefox instead.

Comment: I actually cannot move to Firefox, I'm too used to chrome. I'm gonna start monitoring my ram usage and we'll see. Btw on windows 8.1 I never encountered problems with chrome and ram usage.

Comment: Ok, I just opened 16 tabs in chrome and it freezed. System monitor stopped at abuout 75% ram usage and crashed. The weird thing is it didn't show swap usage. Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Ok, so now it looks you have a problem with your swap. The system always reports some usage, even if a few Mb. Could you post the contents of your `/etc/fstab` file?

Comment: And just to stress my point: using Chrome/Chromium with multiple tabs on a 4 Gb system is not a great idea. Even if you solve this potential Swap issue, we'll end up with a lot of memory transfers from RAM to Swap, reducing performance and stressing the hard drive.

Comment: I don't have swap partition, I didn't think i have to. I'm gonna add 4GB swap and see what happens.

Comment: I think the problem is right there. You're dealing with big ram consumption apps and you only have 4 GB RAM with no swap partition inside. If you're using 17.04, it must be added automatically a **swap-file**. But before 17.04 the system creates a **swap partition**. I think because you don't have a swap partition the computer stuck. Create a swap file/partition and reboot. And monetize your usage using apps like htop(GUI),top(command line app) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried limiting your open tabs to 4-5?

While browsing with different number of tabs open, type `free -m` at a command line to see how much memory you have list. [Manpage for free.](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/free.1.html)

[More suggestion on checking memory used here.](https://superuser.com/questions/793192/what-is-using-up-all-my-memory-ubuntu-14-04-lts-server)

Also use the `top` command in a separate terminal. It will show you all processes running, the memory and cpu % they use. Very handy. Hit 'q' to stop the `top` program. See the man page for various sorting options.